# ASCII SHA1 Hash Ruby

Tags: ruby

I want to generate ASCII SHA1 Hash of a string comprised of the current time (to millisecond) and a salt string (can be anything)

Does someone know how to implement such thing?

Comment: What is an "ASCII SHA1" hash and how does it differ from a regular SHA1 hash?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
require 'digest'
salt="Celtic Sea"
time_now = Time.now
Digest::SHA1.hexdigest("%.3f#{salt}" % time_now)
```

Comment: Why do you want to truncate `Time.now` to three decimals?

Comment: The OP asked for the current time rounded to the nearest millisecond.